# How can I modify the available "repeat" options in a new Calendar event?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, calendar

3I'm creating a calendar that lists various recurring due dates for reports and status updates. For end-of-year reports, I choose the "Last weekday of December" option. However, 31 Dec is a company holiday. I'd like to have this report fall due on 30 Dec.

While I could easily do this with a lookup on the exisiting dueDate fields and an calculated "newDueDate-takingCompanyHolidaysIntoAccount" column, I'm wondering if there's a way to access the list(s) that populate the's calendar "add new task" dialog box to save that extra step?

I would like to define an additional menu option; last *workday* of the month with a list of company holiday dates. I could then define dueDate as such:

```
dueDate = if ((lastWeekday is-in-holidayList) and (lastWeekday = "Monday")) then dueDate = dueDate - 3 else dueDate - 1;
```

...recursively until my dueDate fell on a workday.

Any ideas?

Comment: I would be astonished if you could modify both how the recurrence data is setup and how its interpreted expand the recurring events to display on the calendar/lists.

Comment: On one hand, that's what I'm afraid of. On the other hand, I've found so much stuff that I ~can~ change, either through buried menu settings or programatically, that who knows? We may all be astonished. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did confirm, definitively, that calendar recurrence data cannot be changed anywhere. I ended up creating to identical tasks with different start dates to simulate the modification I was unable to make.